# [UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4.5

I am having a series of `imageview` arranged, and assigning a `TapView` recognizer to it

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(action:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

and I have defined the selector as:

```
-(void) action:(id)sender
  {
    NSLog(@"TESTING TAP");
    NSLog (@"%d",[sender tag]);
  }
```

This is getting Crashed and i am getting Error message as:-

`[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145d0210`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use this..

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(action:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageView.tag = 1111;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

And in action try this..

```
-(void) action:(id)sender
  {
    NSLog(@"TESTING TAP");
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    NSLog (@"%d",[tapRecognizer.view tag]);
  }
```

Explaination:

`UITapGestureRecognizer` has not property like `tag`. but it has property `view`, from this property you can access the view with which `UITapGestureRecognizer` was attached.

Hope it will help you

Comment: Welcome and feel free for any help. And please accept the answer so that other users can get help from your post

Comment: swift equivalent please?? @NiravGadhiya

Answer (score 10):

Just Change your Selector Method with the following..and it will work

tapgesture will have the whole view which is tapped.. and then you can get the tag property from it as i have stated in following

```
-(void)action:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture{

     NSLog(@"TESTING TAP");
        NSLog (@"%d",tapGesture.view.tag);

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Neither `UITapGestureRecognizer` nor `UIGestureRecognizer` declares a property or method called `tag`.

You can't use it. That's why you're getting the error.

On a related note. I really don't like using `tag` in general. There is always a better way to do what you're doing without using `tag`.

Comment: @Wodjefer What are you trying to do with `tag`? i.e. why are you using it? If I know that I can prob suggest a better way.

Comment: Actually, i have a series of imageview arranged and when it scroll through the imageview i shud get the preview..as we have in iphone gallery(ios7)

Comment: Ah, the iPhone Photos app uses a `UICollectionView` to lay out the images. It works a lot like a `UITableView` and does all the tapping for you. That way you don't need the `UITapGestureRecognizer` at all and it's a lot more memory efficient to display all the photos at the same time.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at this tutorial... http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Answer (score 5):

Swift equivalent of the accepted answer:

```
//use this to set up your tap gesture
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.reactToTap(sender:)))
imageView.tag = 33
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

This is the function which gets triggered by the tap:

```
@objc private func reactToTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            
    print("ImageView tag: ", sender.view?.tag ?? 0) //"ImageView tag: 33"
}
```

Comment: this works! I was looking for a Swift solution for ages thanks!

Comment: For anyone who is looking for a solution, do not use sender as a view. use this solution and it will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get `tag` property of `UITapGestureRecognizer` rather you have to get of its view's property,

You can try,

```
-(void)action:(id)sender
  {
     NSLog(@"TESTING TAP");
     NSLog (@"%d",[[sender view]tag]);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The other methods did not work for me!