# Increment Label Value with UIStepper in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistepper

I want to be able to use a UIStepper that is located in each tableview row. I would like each UIStepper to update a label in the same tableview row that the UIStepper is in.

The code that I am trying is as follows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cartListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseCartListingCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CartListingItemTableViewCell

        cartListCell?.UI_STEPPER_NAME.value = VALUE_FROM_ARRAY

        return cartListCell!

}


@IBAction func CartStoreQtyStepperAction(_ sender: UIStepper) {


        // I need to update the value of a label in the tableview cell that tapped

    }
```

**UPDATED IMPLEMENTATION**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        cartListCell?.CartListingProductQtyStepperOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
     cartListCell?.CartListingProductQtyStepperOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CartStoreQtyStepperAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        cartListCell?.tag         =   Int(CartStoreItemIdArray [indexPath.row])!
        return cartListCell!
}


@IBAction func CartStoreQtyStepperAction(_ sender: UIStepper) 
{

            let stepperValue = Int(sender.value)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: stepperValue, section: 0)
            print(stepperValue)

           if let cell = yourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CartListingItemTableViewCell 
    {
        print(cell?.tag)
    }

}
```

I am not able to access the tableview cell and the label in that when I am doing it like this. Can someone guide me how to do this?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739894/how-to-get-indexpath-when-image-inside-cell-tapped/48740036#48740036 and `solution2`

Answer (score 4):

```
// Custom tableview cell code
class CartListingItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

}
```

// your view controller code (tableview data source)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cartListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseCartListingCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CartListingItemTableViewCell

    let stepperValue = yourArray[indexPath.row]
    cartListCell?.label.text = String(stepperValue) ?? "0"
    cartListCell?.stepper.value = Int(stepperValue) ?? 0
    cartListCell?.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
    cartListCell?.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.stepperValueChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

    return cartListCell!

}


// handle stepper value change action
@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ stepper: UIStepper) {

    let stepperValue = Int(stepper.value)
    print(stepperValue) // prints value

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: stepperValue, section: 0)
    if let cell = yourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CartListingItemTableViewCell {
        cell.label.text = String(stepperValue)
        yourValueArray[index] = stepperValue

    }
}
```

Comment: Althought i am able to get the stepper value on the function, i am not able to assign the incremented function to the label in the cell

Comment: Check the question. I have added the implementation that i am trying to do

Comment: check question. I have modified it

Comment: @JobinsJohn - Something is wrong with code you have implemented and sharing here.. `print(cell?.tag) // prints nil` this statement never executes inside `if-let`. As `if-let` ensures your cell value is not nil and if cell value is nil then it will not enter in `if` block

Comment: Note that IndexPath(row: stepperValue, section: 0) should most likely be IndexPath(row: stepper.tag, section: 0)

Answer (score 0):

Assign tag value to sender of `UIStepper` in `cellForRowAt` and access the change of `UIStepper` value in `CartStoreQtyStepperAction` action using same tag.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cartListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseCartListingCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CartListingItemTableViewCell

        //Assign tag value
        cartListCell?.UI_STEPPER_NAME.tag = indexPath.row
        cartListCell?.UI_STEPPER_NAME.value = VALUE_FROM_ARRAY
        cartListCell?.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CartStoreQtyStepperAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

        return cartListCell!
}


@IBAction func CartStoreQtyStepperAction(_ sender: UIStepper) {

    let index = sender.tag
    yourValueArray[index] = sender.value
    //Reload particular cell for tableView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Swift 4 [swift4](/questions/tagged/swift4).

1. Add these lines in `cellforRowAt`.

   ```
   cartListCell.UI_STEPPER_NAME.tag = indexPath.row
   cartListCell.UI_STEPPER_NAME.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CartStoreQtyStepperAction), for: .touchUpInside)
   ```
2. To access cell items in the stepper function use this line.

   ```
   let cartListCell = sender.superview?.superview as! CartListingItemTableViewCell

   //check whether your superview is table cell.
   //then use the cell instance to update the cell label
   ```
3. Use `sender.tag` in the function to access particular cell for example.

   ```
   cartListCell.UI_STEPPER_NAME.text = "\(VALUE_FROM_ARRAY[sender.tag])"

   //sender.tag is similar to indexPath.row as we pass the tag value in the cellforRowAt. 
   //It will work then please accept my answer.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for Swift 4 using `NSKeyValueObservation`

- First of all you need a property in your data model to keep the current value of the stepper.

  ```
  var counter = 0.0
  ```
- In the custom cell create outlets for the stepper and the label and a property for the observation. Connect the outlets.

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var stepper : UIStepper!
  @IBOutlet weak var label : UILabel!

  var observation : NSKeyValueObservation?
  ```
- In the controller in `cellForRow` add the observer, `dataSourceArray` is the data source array.

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cartListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseCartListingCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CartListingItemTableViewCell
      let item = dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]
      cartListCell.stepper.value = item.counter
      cartListCell.label.text = "\(item.counter)"

      cartListCell.observation = cell.stepper.observe(\.value, options: [.new]) { (_, change) in
          cartListCell.label.text = "\(change.newValue!)"
          item.counter = change.newValue!
      }

      return cartListCell
  }
  ```