# Updating UITableView section when select Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm searching for a hint/best practice of how to do the following behaviour. I have a UITableView that contains some sections, every section contains custom UITableViewCells. Example: Section 1 contains a UITableViewCell with a UILabel, section 2 contains one UITableViewCell that contains some UITextFields. When I select a UITableViewCell from the section 1 (a UILabel), I get an Object. Does anyone know how to fill the UITextFields with the variables of the selected object from the section 1?

Here is an example use case: I have a UITableView contains 2 sections, In section one I have list of student names, in section 2 I have one custom UITableViewCell that contains some UITextFields, when I select a name from section 1, I want to get the details of that student in the UITextFields.

Comment: so in your data source add value for textfeild when  user click in first section cell and Reload the tableview.

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739894/how-to-get-indexpath-when-image-inside-cell-tapped/48740036#48740036) to access selected row data from tableview, then add that data in your data source of section 2 for fill info in textfield.

Comment: Its all is the logical part and its lengthy, so first tell us what you have done so far?

Comment: @dahiya_boy for now I just select the cell from the section 1 and I get the object, just I want to update the textfields of the cell in the section 2 with the selected object.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS can you explain me more, please ?

Comment: Show us your data structure.

Comment: show me your code for tableview.. will try to explain on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Notification

in TableViewController:
`public let StudentSelectedNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue: "StudentSelectedNotification")`
in `didSelectRowAt indexPath`:
`NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification.init(name: StudentSelectedNotification, object: MyObject))`
in `viewDidLoad`:
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.fillTextField(_:)), name: StudentSelectedNotification, object: nil)`
in TableViewController:
`func fillTextField(_ notification: Notification) {
        let myObject = notification.object
        // set the text of textfield here
}`