# How to get indexPath from image gesture in table view's cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I've image in cell, I've added gesture recogniser for this image. After deleting a cell from table the indexPath of the cells below the deleted cell is incorrect which cause app to crash.

How do I get indexPath from gesture recogniser when image inside cell is tapped?

I've searched a lot but can't find a working solution. Below is the code which I've right now. This code returns incorrect row.

P.S. Please don't suggest adding button on top of Image as I'm already aware of this.

```
@objc func imageTapped(_ gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    guard let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: gesture.location(in: gesture.view)) else {
        print("Error: indexPath)")
        return
    }

    print("indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48740036/5820010

Comment: I've already seen that solution. Solution 3 : doesn't work, Solution 2: I want to avoid, Solution 1: touchesBegan doesn't fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to change your code little bit instead of gesture.view you need to find location in your tableView

```
@objc func imageTapped(_ gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){

guard let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: gesture.location(in: self.tableView)) else {
    print("Error: indexPath)")
    return
}

print("indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row)")
```

}

and if problem still persists, you can give tag to imageView like this

```
imageview.tag = indexPath.row //place it in cellForRow

//place below lines in gesture handler
guard let view = sender.view else {return}
let indexPath = IndexPath(row:view.tag, section: 0) //only works if section remains same/ unique
```

Comment: Real nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func imageTapped(_ gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    guard let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: gesture.location(in: gesture.view)) else {
        print("Error: indexPath)")
        return
        else{
           path.indexPath(int x);
        }
    }
    print("indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate, can you check your code again, it doesn't make any sense?

Comment: guard let indexPath = myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: gesture.location(in: gesture.view)) else {
    print("Error: indexPath)")
    return
       else{
       path.indexPath(int x);
       }
}

print("indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row)" + "yesitdoesmate")

Comment: Makes perfect sense